# Cypress: Get the url token, save it to local storage and mock the login data to perform an automatic login

Tags: javascript, cypress

I need to login without going through the login screen, that is, with mocked data, because when testing the login directly on the login screen, when authenticating I am redirected to the home screen, where in addition to not being the screen I want to test ends up breaking the test due to a problem with the iframe. Until then I already have the custom command to get the token and save it, I need to hit the url, and with the mocked data automatically log in, and with that redirect to the screen I want to test.

Here's what I have so far:

**Commands.js**

```
import 'cypress-iframe';
import 'cypress-dotenv';
import 'cypress-file-upload';
import 'cypress-localstorage-commands';

const defaultUsername = Cypress.env('user')
const defaultPassword = Cypress.env('password')


Cypress.Commands.add('getToken', (username = defaultUsername, password = defaultPassword) => {
    cy.request({
      method: 'POST',
      url: 'https://testedt04.qa.directtalk.com.br/adminuiservices/api/Login',
      headers: {
        Authorization: `Basic ${window.btoa(`${username}:${password}`)}`,
      },
    }).then((res) => {
        if (res.status === 200) {
            cy.setLocalStorage('dt.admin.token', res.body.token)
            cy.setLocalStorage('dt.admin.siteId', res.body.SiteId)
            cy.setLocalStorage('dt.admin.agentId', res.body.AgentId)
            cy.setLocalStorage('dt.admin.tenantId', res.body.tenantId)
            cy.setLocalStorage('dt.admin.departments', JSON.stringify(res.body.departments))
            cy.setLocalStorage('dt.admin.mnemonic', res.body.mnemonic)
            cy.setLocalStorage('dt.admin.megaMenu', res.body.MegaMenu)
            cy.setLocalStorage('dt.admin.siteName', res.body.siteName)
            cy.setLocalStorage('dt.admin.agentUserName', res.body.agentUserName)
            cy.setLocalStorage('dt.admin.agentName', res.body.agentName)

        }
    })
}
```

**Login.spec.js**

```
/// <reference types="cypress"/>

import signin from '../pages/SigninPage'

describe("Get Token And Save", () => {
    before(() => {
      cy.getToken();
      cy.saveLocalStorage()
    })
  
    beforeEach(() => {
      cy.restoreLocalStorage()
    })
  
    it("Should Exist Token in localStorage", () => {
      cy.getLocalStorage("dt.admin.token").should("exist")
      cy.getLocalStorage("dt.admin.token").then(token => {
        cy.log('Token generated: ' + token)
      })
    })
})

describe('When I login in supervisor', () => {
    before(() => {
        signin.go()
        cy.getToken()
        signin.noException()
        cy.saveLocalStorage()

    })
    beforeEach(() => {
        cy.reload()
        cy.restoreLocalStorage()
    })

    it("Sould Still Exist Token in localStorage", () => {
        cy.getLocalStorage("dt.admin.token").should("exist")
        cy.getLocalStorage("dt.admin.token").then(token => {
          cy.log('Token generated: ' + token)
        })
      })
    
    it('With CORRECTLY credentials', () => {
        signin.login(Cypress.env('user'),Cypress.env('password'))
        signin.verifyLogin(Cypress.env('site'),Cypress.env('agent'))
    })

    it('With WRONG credentials', () => {
        signin.login('não existe','erro')
        signin.verifyErrorLoginMessage(403, 'Credencias informadas invalidas')
    })

    it('With NOT FOUND response request', () => {
        signin.interceptLogin(404)
        signin.login('SEM','erro')
        signin.verifyErrorLoginMessage(404, 'Operação não encontrada')
    })

    it('With SERVER ERROR response request', () => {
        signin.interceptLogin(500)
        signin.login('SEM','erro')
        signin.verifyErrorLoginMessage(500, 'Erro interno no servidor')
    })

})
```

**SigninPage.js**

```
class SigninPage {
 go(){
   cy.visit('/login.html')
 }
 login(user, pass){
    this.go()
    cy.get('#login').type(user)
    cy.get('#password').type(pass)
    cy.get('[ng-show="SHOW_INPUTS"] > .form-wrapper > .form-horizontal > .buttons-wrapper > #loginButton').click()
 }

 verifyLogin(site, agent){
    cy.get('.site-name').should('have.text', site)
    cy.get('.agent-name').should('have.text', agent) 
}

 interceptLogin(code){
    cy.intercept('POST', '/adminuiservices/api/Login', {
        statusCode: code,
        body: {},
    },)
 }

 verifyErrorLoginMessage(code, message){
    cy.get(`[ng-show="hasError(${code})"]`)
    .should('have.text', message)
 }

 noException(){
   Cypress.on('uncaught:exception', (err, runnable) => {
      return false
  })
 }
}
export default new SigninPage;
```

Comment: Is there a specific issue you're running into? Does your existing code not work as expected?

Comment: so I need to login without going through the login screen and redirecting to another url